# Lambda Concurrency Problem With MSK Event Source

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-msk

We are using AWS Lambda With MSK Event Source.

**Environment Details:** Currently we have a total of 47 Partitions assigned to MSK topic that Lambda is listening to.
We have defined Lambda Reserved Concurrency to 47 as well.

We are facing multiple issues as listed below.

**Problem: 1**: When we put events in multiple partitions of MSK topic, Lambda concurrency is not working properly.

We expect that, In case of parallel load (when there are events in all 47 partitions of MSK topic), All the defined Lambda Reserved Concurrency will be used (i.e maximum of 47 Lambda will be invoked concurrently). But In our case only ~2 Concurrent Lambdas were invoked even though there was ~9 invocation requests.

**Problem: 2**: From the Lambda Function Cloudwatch Logs, We found that there is a lag of ~1 minute between MSK event publish time and Lambda Trigger time.

**Kafka Event Message From Logs:**

```
{"records":{"topicName-7":[{"topic":"topicName","partition":7,"offset":27,"timestamp":1632218228728,"timestampType":"CREATE_TIME","key":"*****","value":"*****"}]},"eventSource":"aws:kafka","eventSourceArn":"*****","bootstrapServers":"*****"}
```

**Function Invocation Timestamp:** 2021-09-21T09:58:08.612Z[UTC]

As we can see, timestamp in Kafka Event Message is 1632218228728 i.e 2021-09-21T09:57:08.728Z[UTC] but Lambda Function Invocation Time is 2021-09-21T09:58:08.612Z[UTC].
So, there is a time lag of ~1 minute.

Please suggest,

1. Is our understanding with Lambda Concurrency correct?
2. Are we missing something in our Lambda Configurations?

Comment: Is it for first messages? Could be the issue of cold starts. Maybe you want provisioned concurrency, instead of reserved concurency?

Comment: No, It's not for the first message. Cold Start flag value was false.

Comment: MSK event source does not support parallel (yet). You may want to look for Kinesis

Comment: As per my understanding and from this aws blog: (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/aws-lambda-auto-scaling-msk-apache-kafka/) Lambda starts with one consumer and checks the OffsetLag metric (measure of backlog at source) every minute and scales up or down every 3 minutes. So if Lambda finds that it is not capable to process all incoming records with different partition, it will spin up new instances upto the number of partitions. But if the load is not too much, lambda will process all records from all partitions with few instances only.